# What portion of his earnings should a son contribute to support his parents?

Tags: scripture, dharma, dharma-shastras, parents

Questions:

1. According to Hindu scripture or shastras, what portion of his earnings should a son contribute, to the parents or family?
2. Does this amount vary if the son is married vs. unmarried?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Why not? Why do so many people here expect everyone to have the same knowledge of Shaastras as they do?

Comment: @Sathyam I made some edits to make your question generic as personal-advice questions are off-topic here. Please see this post on meta: [Asking for help / solutions to solve personal issues should be considered off-topic](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/296/2995).

Comment: @sv. Unfortunately replacing "I" with "a person" isn't enough in this case to move the question away from being about a very specific personal situation.  Now a more general question of the form "are children supposed to support their parents" or even "are children supposed to support their parents while their parents are working, or only in their old age", that might be more acceptable.  Also, the whole concept of "percentage of one's salary" is premised on the modern concept of employment.

Comment: This is not a personal question. There is clear guidance in shastra on apportioning one's earnings- a 10th to parents, a 10th to charity, a 6th to taxes, etc. The question must be reopened as it is not a personal one.

Comment: I think the expat part makes it too specific. A general question like how much money should one give to parents...is valid..

Comment: @moonstar2001 Could you provide the source so that I could go back and study it myself? If your comment is valid, I think it is an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I think the question is relevant for me as well as *people like me.* It is rather a reference request than a personal question, but I couldn't find any tag close to *reference request.*

Comment: @Sathyam If you want to remove the details specific to your personal situation, like father currently working and you being an expat, and simply ask "What portion of a person's earnings should be given to parents?" that may be more acceptable.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan. Made some edits. I think the spirit of the question is made clear, feel free to make more edits if you think appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unable to find the exact source on Google, but I remember reading it long back, so moderators may delete this comment, or if anyone remembers the source, you can edit.

1/6th of a man's earnings is taken by King for taxes. Of the remaining 5/6, a man should allocate 1/6 for savings for times of distress, 1/6 for charity for poor and handicapped, 1/6 for daily needs for himself and family (includes wife, children and parents), 1/6 for bandhus (brothers, sisters, relatives in need, friends asking for loans etc.), 1/6 for personal pleasure, and i forgot the last sixth.

Of course, this mainly applies to olden days when mostly vaishyas (merchants) used to earn and they would support brahmins (scholars) and kshatriyas (warriors) by alms and taxes respectively. There was also not much distinction between caring for wife/children vs. caring for parents because they were all part of the 'family'.

Not sure if this is relevant to your question, but once a  man is married, scriptures state his wealth is shared equally by his wife (she has to 'admit' every expenditure, including donations, by sprinkling water, as you can see in almost every Vedic ritual priests conduct).